# Right way of creating a library, installing it and linking to another project using CMake

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, static-libraries

I have a set of files that I want to make into a library and then use that library in another project. This it how it looks like right now

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -fopenmp -fPIC")
add_library (helperlibs lib1.cpp lib2.cpp lib3.cpp lib4.cpp )
INSTALL(TARGETS helperlibs
        DESTINATION "${HOME}/lib"
        )
INSTALL(FILES lib1.h lib2.h lib3.h lib4.h helperheader.h
        DESTINATION "${HOME}/include/helperlibs"
        )
```

In this code `Lib4` depends on `Lib1-3` and `Lib3` depends on `Lib1-2` and `Lib2` depends on `Lib1`. Each of these cpp files also depend on a `helperheader.h` file that contains some definitions and structs.

In my project I have the following CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -fopenmp -fPIC")
SET(MYINCS ${HOME}/include/helperlibs)
SET(MYLIBDIR ${HOME}/lib)
SET(MYLIBS ${MYLIBDIR}/libhelperlibs.a )
include_directories(${MYINCS})
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${MYLIBS})
```

So what I am wondering if you want to create a static library and link to from a another project using cmake is this the way you should write?

Comment: Are you encountering any problems, or are you just asking?

Comment: I am encountering problems and being a bit of a noob I am not sure if it depends on the way I am structuring the libraries and the dependencies it or if it is in the code somewhere.

Comment: Still, you should *post* the problems you're getting. How can we help you if we don't know with *what?*

Comment: So what I am asking if you want to create a static library and link to from a another project using cmake is this the way you should write it or am I missing some crucial point. I can edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, this is *one way* of going about this. But *please,* if you need help sorting out some problems, *post* those problems.

Comment: Unrelated: why are you doing `aux_source_directory()` and never using the results? The call is totally unnecessary in your CMakeLists.

Comment: Aux was mostly a copy paste thing that went along for the ride. I agree on being vague. Will vote to close or and rephrase question.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the search paths into the library target as properties and create an export.
This way executables in the same build tree will find the library and its include files without you having to specify paths (they become implicit).

I needed to read the cmake documentation carefully a few times before it dawned on me how it should work.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages
 http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

excerpt from a live example:

```
add_library(trustportal-util ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${_source_files} ${_disabled_source_files} )
target_link_libraries(trustportal-util ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
if(APPLE)
    find_library(SECURITY_FRAMEWORK Security)
    target_link_libraries(trustportal-util ${SECURITY_FRAMEWORK})
else()
    find_library(LIB_SSL ssl)
    find_library(LIB_CRYPTO crypto)
    target_link_libraries(trustportal-util ${LIB_SSL} ${LIB_CRYPTO})
endif()

target_compile_definitions(trustportal-util PUBLIC BOOST_MOVE_USE_STANDARD_LIBRARY_MOVE)

target_include_directories(trustportal-util PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(trustportal-util PRIVATE
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

target_include_directories(trustportal-util SYSTEM PUBLIC
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

install(TARGETS trustportal-util
    EXPORT trustportal-utilExport
    DESTINATION lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
INSTALL(EXPORT trustportal-utilExport DESTINATION lib)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do what you are currently doing where you place the includes and libs in a common location, perhaps /usr/include and /usr/lib on linux, or ${HOME} on both Windows/Linux, up to you.

Another option is available if you use git. You can include the project inside another using submodules. Then use include_directory(${submodule}) and build and link directly for every project. The advantage of this approach is that dependencies are more localised. One problem with this method is if you recursively do this, you may end up with duplicates of some projects and cmake will complain that two libraries have the same name.